# Runtime Error with referenced WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, wcf, reference

I have created a reference to an IIS hosted WCF service in my ASP.NET website project on my local workstation through the "Add Service Reference" option in Visual Studio 2008.  I was able to execute the service from my local workstation.

When I move the ASP.NET web site using the "Copy Web Site" feature in Visual Studio 2008 to the development server and browse to the page consuming the service, I get the following error:

> Reference.svcmap: Specified argument
>   was out of the range of valid values.

Has anyone experienced this same error and know how to resolve it?

**EDIT:** My development server is Win2k3 with IIS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sixto Saez: I was able to use the following resource similar to the one you provided to generate a proxy class using the ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool (svcutil.exe).

Here is the exact command line:

```
svcutil /t:code http://<service_url> /out:<file_name>.cs /config:<file_name>.config
```

[Here](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/generating-wcf-proxy-using-svcutilexe/) is the reference I found that suggested using the method.

Also, I was able to consume the service by creating a reference using the Visual Studio 2008 "Add Web Reference" command.  It generates code based on .NET Framework 2.0 Web Services technology.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to a mismatch with the solution/project folder structure and the IIS web site folder structure. I ran into similar problems a good while ago and ended up changing how I deploy web services. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/861e66fe-41cd-483c-8418-599d8d5415a8/) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/861e66fe-41cd-483c-8418-599d8d5415a8/) are some discussions of similar problems to yours, they ended up not using the Add Service generated client and rolled their own client. Also, I can vouch for using the "Publish web site" method for deploying my services. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163448.aspx) is a good article on web service deployment models.

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately, the WCF service web site and I can not use the svcutil solution (Unless you know of a way how...).  Do you deploy you service or your web site with the service reference using Visual Studio 2008 publish web site feature?

Comment: I create the web service client using svcutil. I take the code and put in separate class library project. I reference the client project in the service web site project and the publish web site process copies the DLL to the bin folder.

Comment: You can also get the client code from the service client created by VS 2008. Just click the show all files button in solution explorer pane. The generate will in a file named reference.cs (or .vb)